# How does sort() in php arranges directory structure array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, directory, php-7

I am learning php from the official manuel and just got to example #13 on Arrays section https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php When I ran the example code in my local windows 10 with php localserver from command line I observed `sort()` actually unsorting the array. I tried the following code:

```
<?php
// fill an array with all items from a directory
$handle = opendir('.');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    $files[] = $file;
}
print_r($files);
sort($files);
print_r($files);
closedir($handle);
```

?>

The output I get is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .ftpquota
    [3] => Ftp fxg710ehhrpx.xml
    [4] => index.html
    [5] => index.php
    [6] => Logo
    [7] => myphp
    [8] => OnlineSlap.rar
)
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .ftpquota
    [3] => Ftp fxg710ehhrpx.xml
    [4] => Logo
    [5] => OnlineSlap.rar
    [6] => index.html
    [7] => index.php
    [8] => myphp
)
```

As you can see, before using `sort` the array was arranged in alphabetic order, but after `sort()` the order became random.

Why did the array got `unsorted` and what is the expected behaviour of sort?

Thank you.

Comment: It's now in case-sensitive alphabetic order, where `A-Z` come *before* `a-z`

Comment: [natcasesort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) seems to work for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is being sorted in case-sensitive order (the default for [`sort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)), so entries starting with `A-Z` come before those starting with `a-z`. If you want to retain a case-insensitive order, you can call [`sort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with the `SORT_FLAG_CASE` flag in conjunction with `SORT_STRING` to achieve that:

```
sort($files, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_STRING);
print_r($files);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .ftpquota
    [3] => Ftpfxg710ehhrpx.xml
    [4] => index.html
    [5] => index.php
    [6] => Logo
    [7] => myphp
    [8] => OnlineSlap.rar
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/n8dBQ)

Note that dependent on your requirements for sorting filenames like `Test2.jpg` and `Test10.jpg`, you may want to use [`natcasesort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) instead, as that will sort by the numbers as well. For example,

```
$files = array (
    0 => 'test2.jpg',
    1 => 'Test10.jpg'
);
shuffle($files);
sort($files, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_STRING);
print_r($files);

natcasesort($files);
print_r($files);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test10.jpg
    [1] => test2.jpg
)
Array
(
    [1] => test2.jpg
    [0] => Test10.jpg
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/F9N5q)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The Manual, I think is uninformative in saying `Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest`. Cheers bloke.

Comment: @user31782 yes, they could mention that it is by default case-sensitive. They do mention you need to do what I've done specifically to get a case-insensitive sort, so I guess it's implied by that.